# How can I print a part of a file when I reach it?

Tags: c, file, printf

I am new with C, I'm having a problem with this code, I am trying to print when I reach a specific part of a text file, but it doesn't print anything. Here is the code:

```
while(!feof(f)){
    fgets(temp, 150, f);
    if(temp=='****'){
        printf("%s\n", temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Several things: 1) Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) 2) you can't compare strings with `==` and 3) `'****'` isn't a string anyway, and 4) you need to remove the trailing newline. Please see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: Are you able to compile that code without warnings?

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare two string, you have to use strcmp function:

```
if(strcmp(temp,"****")==0 ) { ....
```

otherwise you will just comparing two pointers

Comment: If anything, this is only a partial answer and does not address the real problems behind what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Marco nope,it's the answer

Comment: @pm100 no, the code is still wrong even using `strcmp` and this answer does not address the real problem. You cannot just read chunks of 150 bytes and then compare the initial part of those with `strcmp`. This is not how searching a string in a file works.

Comment: Re “does not compile”: While `'****'` is not what OP needed or wanted, it does compile. C 2018 6.4.4.4 permits character constants to contain multiple characters, and 6.4.4.4 10 says the value is implementation-defined.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli fgets(temp, 150, f); does not read chunks of 150 bytes, it reads line by line each line up to 150 chars

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you really want to use is strstr()

This returns a pointer to the first occurrence of a string inside another string.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm

```
//while there are still lines to read , print if desired line has been read

while(fgets(temp, 150, f)) 
{
  //if beggining mark is found print
   if(strstr(temp, "****")!=NULL) printf("%s\n" , temp)
}
```

Note: 150 should be replaced by a MAXIMUM_LINE_SIZE variable. This variable should be populated with the maximum line size from the file that you are reading from. If a line is longer than this max size you could miss the desired string if "****" is over 150 characters into the line.

Comment: This is definitely better than OP's original solution, but if the string is at the end of a chunk you will not detect it (e.g. `"A"*148 + "****"`).

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that thanks @MarcoBonelli , I am going to make a quick edit.